# Recursive attaching in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asynchronous, entity-framework-core, entity, dbcontext

Let's assume I have two entities, `Folder` and `File` and this is their simplified structure:

```
File
    public virtual Folder ParentFolder

Folder
    public virtual List<File> Files
```

Now imagine the user is asynchronously and rapidly creating multiple files, folders, etc., of course I solved this with creating a new `DbContext` for every operation, so for example when the user creates a folder, I do the following:

```
var file = new File (fileModel);
var folder = context.Attach (GetFromInMemoryCacheById (fileModel.FolderId));
file.ParentFolder = folder;
folder.Files.Add (file);
context.SaveChanges ();
```

and soon I get into a problem where whenever I attach the existing folder, all its children often get attached in Added state. So since I get duplicate key added exceptions, I am forced to additionally do something like this so they get `Unchanged` state:

```
folder.Files.ForEach (file => context.Attach (File));
```

But now image my structure is a bit bigger and I have another layer, for example `Disk`. Suddenly, for even the simplest save action I have to run through a lot of entities to make them be in `Unchanged` state and this really got out of control really fast.

What would be appropriate way for making `DbContext` care only about `File` and its parent `Folder`, but completely ignore the list of `Files` it has so I would not have to fix their states all the time?

Comment: If you add something, its children will be added as well. I'd probably go the route of setting the navigation properties null before adding, and then re-set them to their previous value.

Comment: IMHO, care about the files and check the existence of the `Folder` or `Disk` upon saving.

Comment: Just set parent IDs, no parent *objects*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't want to mess up with ids or set anything to null that shouldn't be null so I ended up setting `[NotMapped]` on `public virtual List<File> Files`. I sacrifised the comfort of this property getting set when loading Folder from database (I have to do it manually, but load operation is very infrequent, mostly I care about continuous saving), but now the unexpected entities no longer get into the scope. Hopefully this approach is helpful to others dealing with asynchronous saving in EF.